# update xml using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a xml with few tags in it and parsing it using python. I wanted to update a tag attribute 'myattrib' value in 'myInterface' tag and save the file. I tried using the xml module as shown below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
tree = et.parse(r'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\myConfig.xml')
tree.find('myInterface').set('myattrib',0)
tree.write(r'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\myConfig.xml')
```

This throws an error

[image]

I googled it and did my research in stackoverflow, its not working for me. Can somebody guide me to achieve this

Comment: I'm not sure but try `tree.find('myInterface').set('myattrib','0')`

Comment: yes i'm doing exactly the same

Comment: so providing second argument as string not integer works?

Comment: yes i tried that, i was able to write the file but its writing only that section and replacing everything else...

Comment: I'm not sure why you use `tree.write(r'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\myConfig.xml')`  In documentation I didn;t find anything about "r"

Comment: 'r is just for processing the link as a raw string, its nothing to do with its working